# Read localstorage where key is an object

Tags: local-storage

I am trying to read a localstorage where key itself is an object. I understand it's a string but still look like an object. Something like this.

```
  {
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2",
    "key3":"value3",
    "key4":"vaule4"
  }
```

The issue is that I know the value of all the keys and few values but not all values. I am not sure how to use localstorage apis to read this object. I am looking for something similar to contains where I can check if key contains this subkey.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do - there are some things to be aware of with `localStorage`. You'll need to parse/serialize to JSON if you plan to store objects in `localStorage`. Further, to detect if an object has a key, you can call `.hasOwnProperty(key_name)` on the object instance which will return either true or false

Comment: Thanks Dacre Denny! hasOwnProperty worked! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect if an object has a key, you can call `.hasOwnProperty(key_name)` on the object instance which will return either true or false